# Can I install Mavericks if I upgrade my RAM?

Tags: macos

I have an early 2008 MacBook with 2GB of RAM and I would like to install OS X Mavericks onto it. However, I am not able to install the OS due to the age of my computer. If I upgrade my computer's RAM (to at least 4GB), will I then be able to upgrade to Mavericks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer....No
If your system is unsupported then you cannot install Mavericks no matter how much memory you have. The problem is with the EFI not the memory.